# Use AffineTransform only for coordinates, but not for text and line style

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d, affinetransform

When using AffineTransform in Java, it gets applied to everything drawn onto the Graphics object. It affects for example the width of lines or flips around the text and makes it much larger.

This is an example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(new DrawPanel());
        pack();
    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JComponent {

        public DrawPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 600));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            AffineTransform scale = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1200 / 360.0, 600 / 180.0);
            AffineTransform mirrorY = new AffineTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 600);

            AffineTransform worldToPixel = new AffineTransform(mirrorY);
            worldToPixel.concatenate(scale);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setTransform(worldToPixel);

            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.drawString("50x50", 50, 50);
            g2.drawString("100x100", 100, 100);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The translation of the coordinates works perfectly: On a 1200x600 pixel component, the above transformation puts 0,0 in the lower left corner and 360,180 in the upper right corner. But the text is mirrored and stretched, too. Also, lines get thicker because of the "scale" transformation.

[Text flipped and stretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVwVi.jpg)

Is there a way to prevent AffineTransform to get applied on text and line styles? So that it works only on coordinates and not on styles?

Comment: You simply need to reverse the rotation and scaling transforms before drawing your lines / text

Comment: If I inverse the transformation, I will lose the translation of the coordinates too.

Comment: read what I said. I did not say to invert the whole transformation.

Comment: I had the same problem in the last 24 hours! To solve it, I used the co-ordinates of the points to create an `Ellipse2D` of diameter 1 pixel, transformed the location and rotation of those ellipses, got the x & y values of the bounding boxes of the transformed ellipses and used **those** values to paint the objects of interest. More generally: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).